# Mongodb Aggregate - how to reference other field in match

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregation pipeline that needs to filter the results by matching two fields

Using a field reference produces no results

```
$match: {
  "item.setid": "$uid"
}
```

Replacing the field reference with a string returns results

```
$match: {
  "item.setid": "example-set-id"
}
```

object schema:

```
{
    uid: <string>,
    item: {
        setid: <string> // references the uid above
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To compare the fields of the document itself, you need to use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) operator

```
$match: {
   $expr: {
     $eq: ["$item.setid", "$uid"]
   }
}
```